# discord.js args not defined with embed message in separate file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Idk what I'm doing wrong, in main file it looks like:

```
    if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix + "help")) {
    client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args);
}
```

And in help.js it's defined like:

```
const Discord = require("D:/Discord Bot/Unfinity/lib/node_modules/discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
name: "help",
description: "Shows standard help menu",
async execute(message, args) {
    const helpui = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor('#994DF7')
    .setTitle("*Unfinity's Help Menu*")
    .addField("8BALL", "Ask the magical ball.")
    .addField("AVATAR", "Previews the avatar of user.")
    .addField("HELP", "Shows this menu.")
    .addField("INFO", "Shows information about the bot.")
    .addField("PING", "Tests Unfinity's response time.")
    .addField("PREFIX", "Displays bot's prefix.")
    .addField("USER", "Shows information about the user.")
    .addBlankField()
    .addField("To view moderation commands use", "**" + config.modprefix + "help**")
    .setFooter("Requested by " + message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL)

    message.channel.send(helpui);
  } 
}
```

I need help with it really, also
[the console error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNoyA.png)

Comment: Where and how is `args` defined in your main file?

Comment: `const args = message.content.split(' ');` @Snel23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a structure like this:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
       if (command == 'help') {
        client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args);
    }
});
```

If you want to learn how to properly create a Discord.js Bot from the Guide written by the Community from discord.js use: https://discordjs.guide

Comment: I get error that args is defined already in `const args = message.content.split(' ');` @plasma-chicken
Should I remove that line or?

Comment: I would recommend you to follow the guide, it will really help you

Comment: I did some rearranging as guide shows and it works, thanks really!